# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openvino'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, pythonpath, openvino, raspbian-buster

I'd like to run some official OpenVINO samples, but I always get the following error:

```
from openvino.inference_engine import IECore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openvino'
```

I created a simple script to test this behavior:

IECore_test.py

```
import sys
from openvino.inference_engine import IECore

ie=IECore()
print("End of test")
```

I'm testing on Raspberry Pi 3B with Movidius `Neural Compute Stick 1 (NCS1)`.
The OS is `Raspberry Pi OS 32-bit (Legacy) Buster` (because `Bullseye` doesn't support NCS1).
OpenVINO Version is `l_openvino_toolkit_runtime_raspbian_p_2020.3.194.tgz`,
which is the last version that can support NCS1.

Here's the procedure to set up OpenVINO:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/intel/openvino
mkdir ~/download
cd ~/download
wget https://storage.openvinotoolkit.org/repositories/openvino/packages/2020.3/l_openvino_toolkit_runtime_raspbian_p_2020.3.194.tgz
sudo tar -xf l_openvino_toolkit_runtime_raspbian_p_2020.3.194.tgz --strip 1 -C /opt/intel/openvino
echo "source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh
sudo usermod -a -G users "$(whoami)"
sh /opt/intel/openvino/install_dependencies/install_NCS_udev_rules.sh
```

I searched on the Internet, then I noticed that `ie_api.so` plays an important role.
I found that `ie_api.so` is located here:

```
/opt/intel/openvino/python/python3.5/openvino/inference_engine/ie_api.so
```

I checked `$PYTHONPATH`:

```
(openvino_env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $PYTHONPATH
/opt/intel/openvino/python/python3.7:
/opt/intel/openvino/python/python3:
/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer:
```

Somehow, `/opt/intel/openvino/python/python3.5` was missing.
(And, there is no `python3.7` directory under `/opt/intel/openvino/python/`, but there is one under `/usr/lib/`.)

So, I ran these two lines:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/opt/intel/openvino/python/python3.5:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH="/opt/intel/openvino/python/python3.5/openvino/inference_engine:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Now `$PYTHONPATH` is:

```
(openvino_env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $PYTHONPATH
/opt/intel/openvino/python/python3.5/openvino/inference_engine:
/opt/intel/openvino/python/python3.5:
/opt/intel/openvino/python/python3.7:
/opt/intel/openvino/python/python3:
/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer:
```

I thought it would work, but `python3 IECore_test.py` returns another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IECore_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from openvino.inference_engine import IECore
  File "/opt/intel/openvino/python/python3.5/openvino/inference_engine/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .ie_api import *
ImportError: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can't find `libpython3.5m.so.1.0` anywhere.
So, I'm stuck here.
How can I resolve these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [l_openvino_toolkit_runtime_raspbian_p_2020.3.355.tgz](https://storage.openvinotoolkit.org/repositories/openvino/packages/2020.3.2/) to import `IECore` on Raspberry Pi.

[image]